# SyntaxError vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
Syntax Error: SyntaxError: C:\Users\Павел\Desktop\Routes-calendar\routes-calendar\src\components\CalendarComponent.vue: Unexpected token (137:17)

  135 |         {value: 1, rout: [pointAlt, pointAshan, pointAlt]}],
  136 | 
> 137 |         pointAlt = { id: 1, label: "Чехов-Альттелеком", name: "205, МЮЗ, ОАО \"Моссковский Ювелирный завод\", г. Химки, Микрорайон Икея, корпус 2", network: 
"Белый ветер Цифровой", endTime: "14:27:15", endDate: "21.01.2018", address: "143090, Краснознаменск, Молодежная д 2/1"},
      |                  ^
  138 |         pointAshan = { id: 2, label: "Ашан-Сити-Орехово", name: "205, МЮЗ, ОАО \"Моссковский Ювелирный завод\", г. Химки, Микрорайон Икея, корпус 2", network: "Белый ветер Цифровой", endTime: "14:27:15", endDate: "21.01.2018", address: "143090, Краснознаменск, Молодежная д 2/1"},
  139 |         pointWeekEnd = { id: 3, label: "Выходной", name: "", network: "", endTime: "", endDate: "",
  140 |         address: ""},
```

Из за чего может быть такая ошибка?

Comment: Учитесь читать ошибки! Компилятор ясно дает понять что допущена синтаксическая ошибка в файле CalendarComponent.vue на строке 137, знак 17. У вас там лишняя скобка.

Comment: В упор не вижу лишней скобки

Comment: разве ide не подсвечивает ничего?

Comment: Нет, все без ошибко, ошибка только при компилировании

Comment: надо искать в синтаксисе ошибку, чудес не бывает

Answer (score 1):

Знак 17 в строке 137 - это неожиданный токен. Не ожидается знак `=`.

Проблема вероятно в предыдущих строках (которые я не вижу) - может быть, что вы строку 135 хотели окончить не запятой (`,`), а точкой с запятой (`;`)?